# a minimization problem about complex number, sum with odd number, when $|z_i=1|$, $s_i$∈ {+1,-1} and $w_i$=1

Tags: discrete-mathematics, complex-numbers, contest-math

There are some complex number $z_1=1,θ=120°$,because $θ=120°$, we can know that $z_2=cos⁡(120°)+isin⁡(120°)= -1/2+i √3/2$, and $z_3=cos⁡(240°)+i sin⁡(240°)=  -cos⁡(120°)-i sin⁡(120°)=  -1/2-i √3/2$. (Like in the circle in the grape, $z_1$ in 0 degree, $z_2$ in 120, $z_3$ in 240).

Now, if $z_i$∈{+1,-1}, we can get min of $|z_1+z_2+z_3|=|1-1/2+i √3/2-1/2-i √3/2|=0$ .

If $w_i=1$, $1≤i≤2n+1$ and a sign number $s_i∈${+1,-1}, how to get min of $|\sum_{i=1}^{2n+1}s_iw_i|=1$, then if$|z_1=1|$, how to prove min of $|\sum_{i=1}^{2n+1}z_iw_i|=0$.

For me, when $s_i∈${+1,-1}, like what I show in the example, s is a sign number 1 or -1, and $w_i=1$, $|s_iw_i|$ always=1, if the number $s_i=1$ and $s_i=-1$ are equal, the extra one is $|s_iw_i|=1$, so min is 1.

Then, when $|z_1=1|$, I don't understand, $|\sum_{i=1}^{2n+1}z_iw_i|=|z_1w_1+z_2w_2+...+z_{2n+1}w_{2n+1}|$ sould be a odd number of $|s_iw_i|$, why =0?

Comment: It seems like you are asking an interesting question that I can't respond to, because I am having trouble interpreting your query.  Two immediate changes that I would advise:  It is clear that you are comfortable with mathJax.  Please edit your query, polishing your use of mathJax to make it more clear.  Also, in the sentence near the beginning of your query : "So, we can get that If $z_i \in \{+1,-1\} \cdots$", I don't understand this statement, so I am **blocked** from trying to go further in understanding your query.  Could you please edit that line to clarify what you are trying to say?

Comment: @user2661923 Yes , I changed it. That means just all of  z's length are 1 or -1

Comment: The mathJax is certainly better - that's 1 down and 1 to go.

Comment: by the way, you can mathJax format a trig expression with something like `$\sin (120^{\circ})$`